# Acumatica and System Crash related to Push Notification Dispatch Errors

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone understand this error or how to further troubleshoot? I see it on the system monitor screen, and the site crashes seconds after this error.

Level: Error
Source: PushNotifications
Event: Push notification queue dispatcher failed
Link to Screen: ~/Main?ScreenId=SM302010
Message: Push notification queue dispatcher failed TenantID:null, TransactionID:null

```
TenantID = 
ContextScreenId = SM302010
SourceContext = PushNotifications
EventID = PushNotifications_DispatcherFailedEventId
Exception = System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Operation was cancelled before it could be completed.
   at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.MoveNext(TimeSpan timeout)
   at PX.Data.PushNotifications.MsmqExtensions.MoveNextWithCancellation(MessageEnumerator queueObserver, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nullable`1 timeout, Action`1 heartBeatDelegate)
   at PX.PushNotifications.PrimaryQueue.MsmqPrimaryNotificationQueue.TryDropUnmatchedCommitFromBeginOfQueue(MessageEnumerator queueObserver, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at PX.PushNotifications.PrimaryQueue.MsmqPrimaryNotificationQueue.TryGetNextTransactionId(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Message& message)
   at PX.PushNotifications.PrimaryQueue.MsmqPrimaryNotificationQueue.ReadNextMessageTransaction(CancellationToken cancellationToken, EventsTransaction& messages)
   at PX.PushNotifications.NotificationQueueDispatcher.ReadNextTransaction(CancellationToken cancellationToken, EventsTransaction& transaction)
   at PX.PushNotifications.NotificationQueueDispatcher.Dispatch(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can error arise when site is restarted by IIS. I suppose your site crashes and this error was logged as the result of crash.